# Unmet dependencies error while installing uuid-dev

Tags: software-installation, 10.04

I'm getting the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  uuid-dev: Depends: libuuid1 (= 2.17.2-0ubuntu1.10.04.1) but 2.17.2-0ubuntu1.10.04.2 is to be installed
```

Haven't been able to find much useful information online.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 1):

Update did not help on Ubuntu 10.04 32bit.

I had to manually download the required package [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/i386/libuuid1/2.17.2-0ubuntu1) and install it:

```
cd
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/41632055/libuuid1_2.17.2-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i libuuid1_2.17.2-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

Your package lists are outdated, you need to refresh it by running:

```
sudo apt-get update
```